# Formula to Combine 2 Different Logic Arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula which will check values of 2 columns and then provide a result in the third column. The cell needs to work with 3 arguments, I hope I'm explaining myself well.

- In column `A` I have a country name, one of the following values:
  *Australia*, *Brazil*, *China*, *Denmark*, *England*, *France*, *Germany*.
- In column `B` I have one of the following colors: *red*, *blue*,
  *yellow*, *green*, *black*.

In column `C` I need a formula to check the following:

- If ***Australia*** is selected in column `A` and column `B` is ***red*** it should say **Yes**
- If ***England*** is selected in column `A` then it should say **Yes** regardless of what's selected in column `B`
- Otherwise, if none of the above are correct then it should say **No**

I have used `=IF(AND(A1<=4,B1<=5),"Yes","No")` this was good with numbers, but I need more than that.

So I used this: `=IF(AND(A1=AUSTRALIA, B1=RED, B1=YELLOW, B1=BLUE),"YES", "NO")` but it would not pick up column b.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Hi thank you for getting back to me. The cell needs to work with 3 arguments. I hope i am explaining myself well. This is what I have in column a (australia, Brazil, China, Denmark, England, France, Germany) in column b i have (red, blue, yellow, green, black). In cell c it needs to calculate that if Australia is selected in column A and column B is red then in column c it should say yes otherwise no. But if in column A is England and if any option is selected in column b it should also say yes in column c as default

Comment: Don't explain your question in a comment, instead [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1783206/edit) and add all the details. Also explain what you want to happen if column a has one of the other country names

Comment: Thanks first time using this. Just did that

Comment: Great! When you write "didn't work" it's always good to write what exactly happened. What the result of the formulas. (Again, edit it into your question.)

Comment: Ok. Any more suggestions on what I could use.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you shortly.

Comment: If your comment is on an answer, then comment on the answer...

Comment: I suggest you share us with a simple sample for better analysis.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to have an `OR` and inside it the two logical scenarios (the first one with an `AND`.)

Your formula `=IF(AND(A1=AUSTRALIA, B1=RED, B1=YELLOW, B1=BLUE),"YES", "NO")` doesn't contain quotation marks around the text words in the logic.

Something like this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1="Australia",B1="Red"),A1="England"),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: This didn't work. I got an error message saying there's a problem with this formula.

Comment: Did you simply copy and paste the whole formula, or you tried to modify any (even small) thing in the formula? When it tells you "there's a problem" it gives you more info about the problem. What does it say?

Comment: I copied and paste the formula. It then comes up with the default error screen you are trying to create a formula

Comment: It works fine for me here, and you can see it in action on Excel Online [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0JkBmOalldx-GUNhlO?e=cu9OUr) as well (you can click File>Save As>Download a copy to open in your local Excel). Not sure what's wrong by you, but can you post a screenshot where we can see the formula bar with the formula entered in it, and the error message?

Comment: Ok thanks. How would it work if column a and column b options were on another sheet (sheet 2).

Comment: Ideally I want it so that if a user chose something in column a and it matched to something we wanted it to in column b then column c would give us a yes if it matches.

Comment: What "***Ok thanks***"? Does it work for you now (if it does, what changed from earlier for you)? Any additional details you want to add you your question [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1783206/edit) and add it there (or - if it's a new question - post a new question with that question.)